# CleanMyMac Damaged MAMP Pro

Tags: macos, mamp

I'm getting this error in my console when starting MAMP Pro after using CleanMyMac:

5/1/11 9:14:46 PM   /Applications/MAMP PRO 1.9/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP PRO[1805]   MDS Error: unable to create user DBs in /var/folders/PM/PMVnHo0lFimPG3mdqsnE+k+++TM/-Caches-//mds

CleanMyMac cleared this file: /var/folders/PM/PMVnHo0lFimPG3mdqsnE+k+++TM/-Caches-//mds

So when MAMP Pro started it tried to read this file but there's nothing there for it to read now.

Any thoughts of how I can reset MAMP Pro to work again?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is an expected result of a cache cleanup, and you should reinstall MAMP to get it to work again.

To prevent such failures in future, you can add MAMP to the Ignore List. Here's how:

1. Open CleanMyMac and click on the Universal Binaries.
2. Click the small 'i' button in the lower right corner.
3. You will find the Ignore List button in the info-tab.

Comment: Thanks I ended up reinstalling SL all together cause a lot of stuff wasn't working after I used it. And I even tried reinstalling MAMP and it still didn't work. Lame. But all is good now.